# How to connect different MongoDB collections to React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, axios

Please help me out with this as I can't find the answer anywhere.

My MongoDB Database name is **myWebsiteDB**:

- **myWebsiteDB** has 2 collections: `dinners` and `emails`.
- I have connected `dinners` collection to use in my website as a CRUD app - works fine.
- Now I want to save data from **Email Subscription section's input field** to the `emails` collection on my website.
- These 2 collections are for saving 2 different data intentions, so I don't want to join them.

I tried setting up the `emails` collection Schema and connecting it to my React App exactly like the way I connected the `dinners` collection before, here are the challenges that I'm facing:

1. When I click the **Submit Email** button, it doesn't work and the **errors** returned from the server's terminal seem like it's the validation for the `dinners` collection, not the `emails` collection that I
   m trying to write in. [See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmBQp.jpg)
2. Am I using [validator](https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js) and writing the new Emails schema right? Do I need to specify the {collection: collection name} like below?

Here are my code:

**Emails Model (Emails.js)**:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const validator = require('validator')

const EmailSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        trim: true,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            validator: validator.isEmail,
            message: 'Please input a valid email address',
            isAsync: false
        }
    }
}, {collection: "emails"})

const Emails = mongoose.model('Emails', EmailSchema)
module.exports = Emails
```

**Dinner Model (Dinner.js):**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const DinnerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    foodName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    isVegetarian: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
    },
    priceRange: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
}, {collection: "dinners"})

const Dinner = mongoose.model("Dinner", DinnerSchema)
module.exports = Dinner
```

**Server side index.js:**

```
const express = require("express") // Set up an express server
const mongoose = require("mongoose") // Import Mongoose library
const cors = require('cors') // Import CORS to communicate with frontend
const app = express() // Initializing our express server

const DinnerModel = require('./models/Dinner')
const EmailModel = require('./models/Emails')

app.use(express.json()) // Setting up Middleware
app.use(cors())

// Connect to MongoDB
mongoose.connect(
    'mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@crud.cvewg.mongodb.net/myWebsiteDB?retryWrites=true&w=majority', 
    {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
    }
)

// Create:
app.post("/insert", async (req, res) => {
    const foodName = req.body.foodName
    const isVegetarian = req.body.isVegetarian
    const priceRange = req.body.priceRange
    const email = req.body.email

    // Dinner Ideas App:
    const dinner = new DinnerModel(
        { 
            foodName: foodName, 
            isVegetarian: isVegetarian,
            priceRange: priceRange,
        }
    )

    // Email:
    const emailData = new EmailModel(
        {
            email: email
        }
    )

    try {
        await dinner.save()
        await emailData.save()
        res.send("data inserted")
        
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
})

// Read:
app.get("/read", async (req, res) => {
    DinnerModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err)
        }
        res.send(result)
    })
})

// Update:
app.put("/update", async (req, res) => {
    const newFoodName = req.body.newFoodName
    const id = req.body.id

    try {
        await DinnerModel.findById(id, (err, updatedFood) => {
            updatedFood.foodName = newFoodName
            updatedFood.save()
            res.send("update")
        }).clone()
    } catch(err) {
        console.log("The error is: " + err)
    }
})


app.delete("/delete/:id", async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.params.id

    await DinnerModel.findByIdAndRemove(id).exec()
    res.send("deleted")
})

// Creating a port:
app.listen(3001, () => {
    console.log("Server is up on: http://localhost:3001")
})
```

**React code with CRUD using the `dinners` collection (DinnerIdeas.js Component)**:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import './DinnerIdeas.css'
import Axios from "axios"
import FoodListComponent from "../FoodListComponent";
import FormComponent from "../FormComponent";


function DinnerIdeas() {

    const [foodName, setFoodName] = useState('')
    const [isVegetarian, setVegetarian] = useState(false)
    const [priceRange, setPriceRange] = useState('$')
    const [newFoodName, setNewFoodName] = useState('')
    const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState([])
  
    // Read:
    useEffect(() => {
      let unmounted = false
      Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/read")
      .then((response) => {
        if (!unmounted) {
          setFoodList(response.data)
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(`Hey, the error is ${error}`)
        return
      })
      return () => {
        unmounted = true
      }
    }, [foodList])
  
    // Create:
    const addToList = () => {
      Axios.post(
        "http://localhost:3001/insert", 
        {
          foodName: foodName,
          isVegetarian: isVegetarian,
          priceRange: priceRange,
        }
      )
    }
  
    // Update:
    const updateFood = (id) => {
      if (newFoodName) {
        Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {
          id: id,
          newFoodName: newFoodName,
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(`Hey, the error is ${error}`))
      }
    }
  
    // Delete:
    const deleteFood = (id) => {
      Axios.delete(`http://localhost:3001/delete/${id}`)
    }
    
    return (
      <section className="dinner-ideas">
        <FormComponent
          setFoodName={setFoodName}
          setVegetarian={setVegetarian}
          setPriceRange={setPriceRange}
          addToList={addToList}
        />
        <FoodListComponent 
          foodList={foodList} 
          setNewFoodName={setNewFoodName}
          updateFood={updateFood} 
          deleteFood={deleteFood}
          newFoodName={newFoodName}
        />
      </section>
    );
  }
  
  export default DinnerIdeas;
```

**React Footer Component that let users put in their emails to subscribe, this will write to the `emails` collection (FooterComponent.js):**

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import Axios from "axios"



export default function FooterComponent() {

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

    const subscribeEmail = () => {
        Axios.post(
            "http://localhost:3001/insert",
            {
                email: email
            }
        )
    }


    return (
        <footer>
            <div>Created by me &copy; 2021</div>
            <div>
                <h3>Interested in further deals?</h3>
                <input
                    type='email'
                    placeholder="Give us your email"
                    onChange={(event) => {setEmail(event.target.value)}}
                />
                <button 
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={subscribeEmail}
                >
                    Submit Email
                </button>
            </div>
        </footer>
    )
}
```

Please guide me on how to fix this, thank you! :)

Comment: What is the body that you are trying to insert? What is the error exactly?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I want the input field to take in the user's email and write it to MongoDB Database. But when I click Submit Button, it takes in the `addToList` axios function that using `dinners` collection (DinnerIdeas.js Component) instead of taking the `subscribeEmail` axios function (FooterComponent.js).

The error said Dinner validation failed, the value of foodName, isVegetarian,.. are required.

But the point is I'm not trying to write to the `dinners` collection and not using the Dinner Schema either. It just doesn't take in the Email Schema of the Email Section.

Comment: You are though in /insert endpoint. You use the dinner schema to make a dinner document and you save it, in addition to the email schema. If you don’t want to make a dinner document, why in /insert are you making one? Which endpoint are you talking about then?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky I see what you mean. So we can't use the same /insert endpoint for different document. If now I want to use /subscribe endpoint for the email: where should I put the app.post("/subscribe"...) code? Can I put it in the same index.js file?

Comment: You can put endpoint code anywhere you want. But yeah, either have conditional logic to only perform the database operations you specifically want or divide the endpoints to handle different schemas.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Thank you! Your comment helped me solve my problem :D